# Python select match - OpenERP

Tags: python, sql

With the following function I'm trying to identify if a column already have X value.

```
def error_verify(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
        nr = int(record.nr_service) # Gets the current value from field

        cr.execute("SELECT nr_service FROM services WHERE nr_service = %s", [nr])
        values = cr.fetchall()

        if values: # if there's ANY result it means there's at least one 
                   # row with that value in the table
           return True
    return False
```

The function is called this way:

```
_constraints = [
        (error_verify, 'Error: Already that ID in the table', [''])
    ]
```

The thing is: I'm not getting any results. I'm trying to get the error message, but I can't reach there. I put some existing values inside the "record.nr_service", but it doesn't throw any message. My question is: Am I doing the function right?

I also tried this way:

```
 def error_verify(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
            nr = int(record.nr_service) # Gets the current value from field

            cr.execute("SELECT nr_service FROM services WHERE nr_service = %s", [nr])
            values = cr.fetchall()

            for n in values:
                if nr == int(n[0]):
                   return True
        return False
```

And in this situation, also doesn't throw any message.

How can I solve it?

Comment: You're being too general for anyone to be able to discern what your function is even trying to do. You say "have X value", but you don't use a variable "X". If you describe what you need and what is going wrong better, then maybe we can help. Code is useful, but generally not when the purpose isn't given

Comment: What you don't understand? I want to verify if there's any value in the table 'Services', in the column 'nr_service' with the value of X. If there's any value it should return True, otherwise, should return False.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've been testing and I think I found where my error is. Let's say I have the value "3" in the database. So, whenever I write the value "3" in the field it should display a error message, otherwise it let me go free.

This works:

```
def error_verify(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        cr.execute("SELECT nr_service FROM services WHERE nr_service = %s", (3,))
        values = cr.fetchall()
        if values:
            return False # Returning false means that there's already a value "3" in the database.
        return True
```

This also works:

```
 def error_verify(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
            cr.execute("SELECT nr_service FROM services WHERE nr_service = %s", (55,))
            values = cr.fetchall()
            if values:
                return False
            return True # it returns true, it let me go free, because I don't have any value of "55" in the database
```

The problem here is that I can't tell the value "3" in the query, I should get that value from a field -> OpenERP field -> like this way:

```
for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context): # loop through the fields
    nr_value = record.nr_service # this is the field
    cr.execute("SELECT nr_service FROM services WHERE nr_service = %s", (nr_value,))
    values = cr.fetchall()
    if values:
      return False
return True
```

With this code it retrieves me the message of error (which is on the 1st post) **no matter the value** I put inside the field. So, the problem must be on the loop. But I really need to get the value from that field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
def verify_service(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        record = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)[0]
        rec_value = str(record.nr_service)
        cr.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM services WHERE nr_service = %s", [rec_value])
        values = cr.fetchone()
        if values[0] <= 1:
            return True
        return False
```